# MongoDB Ops Manager change URL root path

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I installed MongoDB Ops Manager in our on-prem kubernetes cluster following these steps: https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/stable/tutorial/deploy-om-container/.

It seems to work and it is accessible (at `http://localhost:8080/`) when doing:
`kubectl -n mongodb port-forward service/ops-manager-svc 8080:8080`

The problem is that I'd like to access the service it provides via our HAProxy ingress, not by port forwarding.

If I configure the ingress as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mongo-ops-manager-ingress
  namespace: mongodb
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /mongodb
        backend:
          serviceName: ops-manager-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

I have to access the service at the `http://<public ip>/mongodb` URL, which confuses the Ops Manager since it looks in the root for its resources, not in `/mongodb` in order for haproxy to pick up the requests and route them accordingly.

I have two other applications set up this way (our application and Grafana) and both work fine.
Now to the question:
Is there a configuration directive (apart from [mms.centralUrl](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/configuration/#mms.centralUrl) which doesn't seem to work) that allows us to modify the root path of the Ops Manager application?

I'm looking for something similar to the `root_url` property of Grafana: https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1

Comment: Why does centralUrl not work?

Comment: This seems like the right setting to me.

Comment: I've set it to `http://domain.name/mongodb`, the URL which should be accessible via HAProxy, and it is, but the page still doesn't load resources such as CSS and JS files. When the Ops Manager page loads it still tries to go to `http://domain.name/` to get those resources.

Comment: Add some urls that are not working properly.

Comment: @D.SM Yes, sorry for the late response. I access `http://addr/mongodb`, but in the developer console I see: `http://addr/static/dist/bem-components.css?_ds=` notice that `/mongodb` is missing from the path. I've set `mms.centralUrl` to `http://addr/mongodb`, but apparently without success.

Comment: Try adding a slash at the end of central url.

Comment: I've tried adding a "/" at the end, same results.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Ops Manager myself but looking at the source I see some asset references like this:

```
<img src="{{centralUrl}}/static/images/icon-alert.png" width="30"
```

And some references like this:

```
<img class="not-found-image" src="/static/images/sadface.gif" />
```

... suggesting that `centralUrl` is the right parameter to set but perhaps it is not respected everywhere, specifically for `/static` assets.

I suggest taking a closer look at your running installation to see if the path specified in `centralUrl` is respected anywhere at all, if it is then that would be consistent with it being partially respected.

You can try setting up aliasing/URL rewriting in your web server to alias `/static` to `/mongodb/static`.

Then, regardless of outcome, this entire issue seems appropriate to escalate to MongoDB via the official support channels if you are a paying customer, otherwise I would inquire at https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/.